# .htacces redirect with special signs

Tags: .htaccess

Need help ;)
How to redirect this link?

mydomain.com/selbständige?catid=141&id=141:kredit-für-selbstständige-ohne-schufa

Tested with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+&)?selbstÃ¤ndige?catid=141(&.+)?$
RewriteRule ^/$ http://test.com? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+&)selbst%E4ndige?catid=141(&.+)?$
RewriteRule ^/$ http://test.com? [R=301,L]

redirect 301 "/selbständige?catid=141&id=141:kredit-für-selbstständige-ohne-schufa" http://test.com
```

...and so on.
No normal workflow works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /selbst.+ndige\?catid=141&id=141:kredit-f.+r-selbstst.+ndige-ohne-schufa [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://test.com? [L,R]
```

I  used **.+** to match against special chars in the uri.